# Pokemon DSV File? Transfer to New Game

Tags: android, emulation

How do I transfer my Pokemon from one save in one game to the next game via DSV file? I use an Android emulator. Do I transfer to sav itself? I don't really have access to a computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your two saves in [PKHeX](https://projectpokemon.org/home/files/file/1-pkhex/).

You'll need a computer to access as DeSmuMe (where DSV files are usually created) is a PC-based application, though it has been ported to Android, Wii, Nintendo Switch and various other systems.

---

As for handling the save file itself; just use a [File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) app.

Comment: You may want to note the `.dsv` and `.sav` files can be converted to the other with a file explorer by simply renaming them, at least with with `.dsv` files created by DraStic, which OP may be using.

Comment: And by extension, you can just open a .dsv file with PKHex. As long as the format is the same, PKHex doesn't care. I can call it `save.totallynotadatfile` and it'll still understand it.